# redmine icalender export plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar, redmine-plugins

I am trying to install Redmine ICalendar Export Plugin(https://github.com/planio/redmine_icalendar_export) and this plugin require icalendar, I tried to install it using `"gem install icalendar"` . But after installation calender part stopped working and showing error `"Internal error An error occurred on the page you were trying to access."`

In the log file I am getting following error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (No route matches {:action=>"index", :status=>"all", :controller=>"calendar", :assigned_to=>"*", :format=>"atom", :project_id=>#<Project id: 3, name: "test project", description: "", homepage: "", is_public: true, parent_id: nil, created_on: "2013-01-08 06:03:05", updated_on: "2013-02-16 04:02:42", identifier: "testproject", status: 1, lft: 5, rgt: 6>, :key=>"268944ce53edddhsjhhgyuh57678dff5f3a0db719323c"}) on line #5 of vendor/plugins/redmine_icalendar_export-master/app/views/hooks/redmine_icalendar_export/_view_calendars_show_bottom.html.erb:

2:      <% other_formats_links do |f| %>
3: <%= f.link_to 'ICS', :url => { :status => 'all',  :assigned_to => '*', :controller => 'calendar', :action => 'index', :project_id => @project, :key => User.current.rss_key, :format => 'atom' } %>
6:      <% end %>
7: <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problem in that plugin, I tried following plugin and it is working fine .

https://github.com/thegcat/redmine_ical